# Logging using colorlog is producing dull gray color instead of white color for log messages

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am using colorlog package along with logging module to get colored logs.
I want the message of logs to be in white. My console is dark in color (using dark background). However instead of white, logs are coming in dull gray color. What setting should I change?

**Code** is as below:

```
import logging
import colorlog

log_colors = {
    'DEBUG': 'blue',
    'INFO': 'green',
    'WARNING': 'yellow',
    'ERROR': 'red',
    'CRITICAL': 'red,bg_white',
}


formatter = colorlog.ColoredFormatter(
    '%(log_color)s[%(levelname)s] %(reset)s %(white)s %(message)s %(reset)s',
    log_colors=log_colors,
)

logger = logging.getLogger('mtgenpl')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

**Screen shot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is something related to how you're configuring that formatter. The formatter string you're using seems to reset the color for the piece of string following.

The configuration also seems weird.
Following is the setup I'm using to achieve white on INFO level:

```
import logging
import colorlog

logging_level = logging.DEBUG
log_colors = {
    'DEBUG': 'cyan',
    'INFO': 'light_white',
    'WARNING': 'yellow',
    'ERROR': 'red',
    'CRITICAL': 'bold_red',
}

formatter = colorlog.ColoredFormatter('\n%(log_color)s[%(levelname)s]: %(message)s', log_colors=log_colors)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = colorlog.getLogger('bot_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging_level)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.debug('hello, world')
logger.info('hello, world')
logger.warning('hello, world')
logger.error('hello, world')
logger.critical('hello, world')
```

`light_white` is used as per a github issue on the colorlog repository. Please visit that repo for further info.